# Not able to fetch response from HttpClient POST method using Angular 7, .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, angular, angular-httpclient

I am creating quite basic implementation of CRUD methods using Angular and ASP.NET Core in the back end.

The back-end work perfectly, but cannot get the response after redirect action.
Let me bring  the code:

**the C# Controller bit:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(IActionResult))]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CapCustomerResponseDto>> CreateCustomer([FromBody] CreateCustomerRequestDto request)
    {
        try
        {
            ///. .. *creating command*

            await _createCustomercommandHandler.Execute(command);
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetCapCustomer", new { id = command.Id.ToString() }, command);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Some custom handling
        }
    }
```

So at the end we have the magical **CreatedAtRoute()** method, which redirects to the get controller

**the Angular 7 httpClient implementation**

```
  addCustomer(customer): Observable<Customer> {
    return this.http.post<Customer>(apiUrl, customer, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((customer: Customer) =>
        console.log(`added customer w/ id=${customer.customerId}`)
      ),
      catchError(this.handleError<Customer>("addCustomer"))
    );
  }
```

which actually returns nothing. 
My customer is added properly, I can see it in the database. When using swagger, I can see the controllers working. Even in Network monitor.
but I have no clue how to retrieve the newly created customer response into my TS classes

Instead I get this:

```
Error: The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1
```

from Console

Question. 
How can I make this work?

Comment: what is `apiUrl`? What URL is being requested?

Comment: since the route is changing after executing the command, maybe the angular code is not able to observe data from that change

Comment: @leggo API working fine ? did you check Postman?

Comment: @DanielA.White, http://localhost:53974/api/Customer .nothing special :)

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran entire API is working properly, all endpoints are working just fine. I just cannot retrieve data from POST, where the redirect is handled on back-end side.:(

Comment: i'd check your browser console/network tab to see whats going on.

Comment: @DanielA.White my console returns a new created customer. just Agular cannot "see" it.